# Check if a integer is present at the end of my string?

Tags: java

I would like to check if a number is present at the end of my string, to then pass this number (an id) to my function. Here is what I realized for the moment:

```
String call = "/webapp/city/1"; 
String pathInfo = "/1";


    if (call.equals("/webapp/city/*")) { //checking (doesn't work)
            String[] pathParts = pathInfo.split("/");
            int id = pathParts[1];  //desired result : 1
            (...)
    } else if (...)
```

Error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error : /webapp/city/1

Comment: Use the right tool for the job: JAX-RS, Spring-MVC, Restlet, or whatever REST framework. But, well, your code doesn't make sense: /webapp/city/* can't possibly **equal** /webapp/city/1. The last character is obviously not the same. And a String array contains Strings, so its second eement can't possibly be an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`matches(...)` method of `String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if your string matches a given pattern:

```
if (call.matches("/webapp/city/\\d+")) {
    ... //                      ^^^
        //                       |
        // One or more digits ---+
}
```

Once you get a match, you need to get element `[2]` of the `split`, and parse it into an `int` using [`Integer.parseInt(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(pathParts[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final String call = "http://localhost:8080/webapp/city/1";
int num = -1; //define as -1

final String[] split = call.split("/"); //split the line
if (split.length > 5 && split[5] != null) //check if the last element exists
    num = tryParse(split[5]); // try to parse it
System.out.println(num);

private static int tryParse(String num) 
{
    try 
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(num); //in case the character is integer return it
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        return -1; //else return -1
    }
}
```